# How to achieve opencl kernel pipeline

Tags: linux, opencl, fpga, hpc

I am working on my project using OpenCl. In order to improve the performance of my algorithm, is it possible to pipeline a single kernel? If a kernel consists of many steps, lets say A,B,C, I want A accept new data as soon as it finish its part and pass it to B.  I can create channels between them, but I dont know how to do it in detail.

Can I write A,B,C(3 kernels) in a .cl file ? but how to enqueueNDRange?
I am using Altera SDK for FPGA HPC development.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Pipeline can be achieved by using several kernels connected with channels. With all kernels running concurrently, data is transferred from one to another:

[Pipeline example from Intel FPGA OpenCL SDK Programming Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9lTz.png)

Very basic example of such pipeline would be:

```
channel int foo_bar_channel;
channel float bar_baz_channel;

__kernel void foo(__global int* in) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    int value = in[i];
    value = clamp(value, 0, 255);                 // do some work
    write_channel_altera(foo_bar_channel, value); // send data to the next kernel
  }
}

__kernel void bar() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    int value = read_channel_altera(foo_bar_channel); // take data from foo
    float fvalue = (float) value;
    write_channel_altera(bar_baz_channel, value); // send data to the next kernel
  }
}

__kernel void baz(__global int* out) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {n
    float value = read_channel_altera(bar_baz_channel);
    float s = sin(value);
    out[i] = s;                                  // write result in the end
  }
}
```

You can write all kernels in the a single .cl file, or use different files and then #include them into a main .cl file.

We want all our kernels run concurrently, so they can accept data from each other. Since only in-order command queues are supported, we have to use different queue for each kernel:

```
cl_queue foo_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(...);
cl_queue bar_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(...);
cl_queue baz_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(...);

clEnqueueTask(foo_queue, foo_kernel);
clEnqueueTask(bar_queue, bar_kernel);
clEnqueueTask(baz_queue, baz_kernel);

clFinish(baz_queue); // last kernel in our pipeline
```

Unlike OpenCL programming for GPU, we rely on a data pipelining, so NDRange kernels would not give us any benefit. Single work-item kernels are used instead of NDRange kernels, so we enqueue them using clEnqueueTask function. Additional kernel attribute (reqd_work_group_size) can be used to mark a single work-item kernel, to give the compiler some room for optimizations.

Check the Intel FPGA SDK for OpenCL Programming Guide for more information about channels and kernel attributes (specifically, section 1.6.4 Implementing the Intel FPGA SDK for OpenCL Channels Extension):

https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/opencl-sdk/aocl_programming_guide.pdf

Comment: "Channels" seem vendor-specific. Aren't "Pipes" supposed to be the way to do this? (I'm asking, not saying; you obviously know tons more about FPGA OpenCL than I do).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying Andrew. So to make different kernels work at the same time I need to use clEnqueueTask to enqueue my kernels instead of EnqueueNDRange?  And also create my kernels and command queue respectively for all my kernels?

Comment: And would the compiler pipeline my single kernel automatically? eg. for(round=0;round<N;round++)  would the loop be pipelined by compiler(accept new data for every single round) or just be executed round by round(accept new data after N rounds).

Comment: @Dithermaster, right, pipes are another way to do the same
thing. For Intel (Altera) FPGA they are not fully compatible with
OpenCL 2.0 Pipes specification, but they still good in terms of
code portability, as you mentioned. If portability is not in
question, difference between pipes and channels is mainly in
syntax.

Comment: @HaominJ, to enqueue a single work-item kernel, either
clEnqueueTask or clEnqueueNDRange with global work size (1,1,1)
would work.

"would the loop be pipelined by compiler(accept new data for
every single round) or just be executed round by round(accept new
data after N rounds)" - if a channel is not buffered, then on every
iteration data would be transfered to the other kernel. For
buffered channels it can be different (see
1.6.4.5.7 "Implementing Buffered Channels Using the depth
Channels Attribute")

Comment: OK I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AndrewSavonichev Hi, I have figured out these two types of kernels recently. But I realized that if I use the single work-item kernel (task parallelism), then I may not achieve data parallelism at the same time.